# Substitute to pstat.h in linux when moving C code from HP-Unix to Linux

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I am porting an application(in C language) from HP-UX to Linux(icc compiler). i have a problem with pstat.h. It's there only in HP-UX but not in Linux and im getting error "pstat_getproc is undeclared". Is there any alternate solution to this? Is there any substitute for sys/pstat.h? As of now I am planning to replace that whole code with something that will work on Linux. Looking forward to your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent; the whole family of `pstat` functions is extremely HP/UX specific. Probably the closest equivalent is the `/proc` interface -- to get information on the current process, for instance, one can examine the pseudofiles in `/proc/self`.

You will, indeed, probably need to replace most of the code which makes use of `pstat`.

Comment: Yes, i was also thinking the same. Thanks.